Bijection between sections of a scheme over $K$ and points with residue field isomorphic to $K$
Let $X$ be a scheme over the field $K$, i.e. there is a morphism $\pi: X\to \operatorname{Spec} K$.
Recall that a section for $\pi$ is by definition a morphism $\sigma: \operatorname{Spec} K\to X$ such that $\pi\circ\sigma=1_X$.
For $x\in X$, let $K_x:=O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m_x$ be the residue field; then there is a canonical morphism $\operatorname{Spec} K_x\to X$ whose image is $\{x\}$.
Question. I read on my notes that there is a bijection between the set of sections for $\pi$ and the set of points $x\in X$ with residue field isomorphic to $K$. However I only managed to see a map from the first set to the latter; I ended up having issues with injectivity and surjectivity. Below is my attempt.
(1) Let $\sigma $ be a section for $\pi$. Its image is a point, say $\bar\sigma\in X$. I understood that $$ \operatorname{Spec} K_{\bar\sigma}\to X\xrightarrow{_\pi}  \operatorname{Spec} K$$ is a isomorphism, and so it must come from an isomorphism  $K\to K_{\bar\sigma}$. Thus the rule $\sigma\mapsto \bar\sigma$ defines a map from the sections for $\pi$ to the points in $X$ with residue field isomorphic to $K$; we need to prove that such map is bijective.
(2) Injectivity. If it was true that ($*$) the isomorphism $\operatorname{Spec}K_{\bar\sigma}\to\operatorname{Spec} K$ of (1) commutes with $\operatorname{Spec} K_{\bar\sigma}\to X$ and $\sigma$, then injectivity would be easy to prove.
Suppose in fact that $\sigma,\sigma'$ are sections for $\pi$ whose image is the same point, say $\bar\sigma=\bar\sigma'=:s$. Assuming ($*$), then $$\operatorname{Spec}K_{s}\to\operatorname{Spec}K\xrightarrow{_\sigma} X$$ and $$\operatorname{Spec}K_{s}\to\operatorname{Spec}K\xrightarrow{_{\sigma'}} X$$ would coincide (with $\operatorname{Spec}K_s\to X$), so $\sigma=\sigma'$, as $\operatorname{Spec}K_s\to \operatorname{Spec}K$ is an isomorphism.
However I'm not very convinced that ($*$) holds, and I don't have other ideas.
(3) Surjectivity. This confuses me even more. Let $s\in X$ be a point such that there is an isomorphism $\alpha:K_s\to K$. Then I would define a section by $$\operatorname{Spec} K\xrightarrow{_{\operatorname{Spec}\alpha}}\operatorname{Spec}K_s\to X$$ but, actually, I'm not convinced that this morphism is a section, and I don't have other ideas either.
I hope that I have been clear in stating my problems, thanks for any clarify.

The statement is true but "residue field isomorphic to $K$" has to be interpreted as "isomorphic to $K$ as a $K$-algebra," not just as a field. Otherwise it's false.
This is a local question so I'll only discuss the case that $X = \text{Spec } A$ is affine. So $A$ is a commutative $K$-algebra, and a section is just a $K$-algebra morphism $A \to K$. The kernel of such a thing is a maximal ideal $m$ with residue field isomorphic to $K$ (as a $K$-algebra), so there is a map between these things. And it is a bijection! Its inverse is given by associating to a maximal ideal $m$ with residue field isomorphic to $K$ the quotient map $A \to A/m$. Because $A$ is a $K$-algebra, so is the quotient $A/m$, and if $A/m \cong K$ as a $K$-algebra then the $K$-algebra structure on $A/m$ is unique (given by the inclusion of the identity) so $A/m \cong K$ canonically.
If we only interpret "residue field isomorphic to $K$" to mean isomorphic as an abstract field then there are silly counterexamples given by taking any field $K$ with a nontrivial embedding $j : K \hookrightarrow K$ into itself (for example $\mathbb{Q}(x^2) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}(x)$), then taking $A$ to be the $K$-algebra structure resulting from this embedding.

$\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$The statement given by you/your notes is not completely accurate, or at least it is possible to interpret it as an incorrect statement. I (and Qiaochu's answer which came just as I was writing mine) give the precise statement below.
Let me call $\xi$ the unique point of $\spec K$. The data of a scheme morphism $\sigma:\spec K\to X$ is the data of a point $x=\sigma(\xi)\in X$ and a local morphism of locally ringed sheaves $\sigma^\#:\mathscr{O}_X\to\mathrm{Sky}_x(K)$ (notice the pushforward from a point is exactly the skyscraper functor). This last condition is, by the stalk-skyscraper adjunction, exactly the data of a map $\sigma':\mathscr{O}_{X,x}\to K$,... such that for all points - well, there is only one - we have $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}\overset{\sigma^\#_{\sigma(\xi)}}{\longrightarrow}(\mathrm{Sky}_x(K))_x\to\mathscr{O}(\spec K)_\xi=K$ is a local homomorphism. This clearly reduces to the condition that $\sigma':\mathscr{O}_{X,x}\to K$ is a local homomorphism, and because $K$ is a field, this means that $\sigma'$ factors through the residue field as a map $K_x\to K$.
So, already I observe scheme morphisms $\sigma:\spec K\to X$ are in bijection with points $x$ and choices of field embedding/extension $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x\hookrightarrow K$. Now we need to figure out what it means for $\pi\sigma=\mathrm{Id}$. If we carefully use the definition of composition of a morphism of schemes and then apply the adjunction $(\pi\sigma)^\ast\dashv(\pi\sigma)_\ast$, it is possible to see that this is exactly the condition that (as morphisms of sheaves over the space $\spec K$ i.e. just maps of local rings) $K\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow}\mathscr{O}_X\to\mathscr{O}_{X,x}\overset{\sigma'}{\longrightarrow}K$ is identity. Fitting in the quotient $\mathscr{O}_X\to K_x$, we realise this is the statement that $K\to K_x\to K$ is identity. In other words, that $\sigma'$ induces an isomorphism of fields $K_x\cong K$ over K, since we must recall $K_x$ canonically contains a copy of $K$ due to the structure morphism $\pi$ and this appears in the above. Note that if $x$ has this condition, it can only have it in one possible way; the map $K\to K_x$ is given, and it either is an isomorphism (with inverse $\sigma'$) or it isn't.
Therefore we are done; sections of $\pi$ are in exact correspondence with points (not necessarily closed) $x$ of $X$ such that the canonical inclusion/algebra map, coming from $\pi$, $K\to K_x$ is an isomorphism.
